# New offspring with different sex

Tags: netlogo

am a new user of Netlogo programme, I want to make a model to to know to what extend badger (vaccination, culling, or combination between both control strategies) can reduce bovine tuberculosis prevalence within badger population. the model is agent-based spatial stochastic model. the agents in Netlogo represent the individual badgers. and the space will be represented as a grid of cells ( each cell will represent a badger territory (a group home range (group size will vary from minimum 2 to 10 badgers))), then badgers will be allowed to move . badgers will be allowed to breed and reproduce one a year (time-step) at a rate recorded from empirical studies and also they will die t mortality rates recorded in studies. I want to make new offspring random number between 1 and 3, with differnt gender ( male and female with sex ratio 1:1) and after 1 year the baby badger become adult

I only want now to form the family and the groups ( each family in one hex)

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [badgers badger]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
badgers-own [ age 
gender 
adult-age
]
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to setup
clear-all
set-default-shape nodes "hex"
;; create a hex grid of nodes
ask patches
[ sprout-nodes 1
[ set color white  ;; the color of the hex patches is white 
set size 1.2
;; shift even columns down
if pxcor mod 2 = 0
[ set ycor ycor - 0.5 ] ] ]
;; connect the nodes to make a lattice
ask nodes
[ ifelse pxcor mod 2 = 0
[ create-links-with nodes-on patches at-points [[0 1] [1 0] [1 -1]] ]
[ create-links-with nodes-on patches at-points [[0 1] [1 1] [1 0]] ] ]
ask links [ hide-link ]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ask patches [
sprout-badgers 1 
[set size 0.2
set color pink
set age 0
set age adult-age + 1
set gender "female"
if pxcor mod 2 = 0
[ set ycor ycor - 0.5 ]]]
ask patches [
sprout-badgers 1 
[set size 0.2
set color blue
set gender "male"
set age 0
set age adult-age + 1
if pxcor mod 2 = 0
[ set ycor ycor - 0.5 ]
]]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
ask badgers [
let male-num-per-group  count badgers-here with [color = blue ] 
let female-num-per-group count badgers-here with [ color = pink]   
ask badgers [ if  male-num-per-group >= 1 [ create-a-newborn]
ask badgers 
[ if  female-num-per-group >= 1 [ create-a-newborn]]]]
end 


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 to create-a-newborn
 create-badgers random 4 
end
```

but always give me error like I cant use create-a-newborn as a turtle context because create-a-newborn is observer only.

regards Marwa

Comment: As I wrote in a comment on an earlier question, I recommend that you take the time to create a Minimum Working Example rather than dumping your whole program into the question. (In this case it didn't matter--my guess is that @JoseMVidal was able to answer the question based on the error message alone.)  One strategy for creating an MWE is to comment out lines that don't seem relevant to the problem.  See if you still get the problem.  If the problem goes away (and you haven't answered your question) put that line back.  Repeat until you have a simple program that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Mars thank you I will try as You said , I am sorry I am only two weeks using the programme .

Comment: No problem user3526846!  I'm just trying to be helpful.  NetLogo is a great programming environment, and I'm happy to see someone else get started on it.

Comment: Dear @Mars , If you dont mind please , can I contact u in by Email or whatever? I make alot in my model but I need help in the base of my model . if not it is fine no worries.

Comment: user3526846, I'd like to help, but I'm overwhelmed by work for my job right now, so I won't be able to do so.  I recommend posting in the NetLogo Google group.  You can ask a wider range of questions there than you can ask on StackOverflow (even though I prefer StackOverflow for some questions).

Comment: @Mars no problem at all, and really thank u for your reply , I will try to make it simple than this and post it again may be some one can help in this thank u again.

Comment: Mars, I think you mean Yahoo group, not Google group: https://groups.yahoo.com/group/netlogo-users/ . But actually, I think SO is best for beginner coding questions. It takes too long to get help on netlogo-users (several days, usually).

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, only the Observer can `create-turtles`. A turtle, however, can`hatch-turtles`, patches can `sprout-turtles`

So, try `hatch-badgers` instead.

Comment: user3526846, if you're not sure what the Observer is, it's the box at the bottom of the GUI screen.  You can type in commands there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. but If i use    hatch-turtles  it give me thousands of foffspring and from male and females.

Comment: You have `ask badgers [ ... hatch ... ]`, so all the badgers have offspring, regardless of sex. If you want to restrict it to female badgers, you have to say so.